# using fetch and json in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to use the following in the same query but server throwing syntax error

```
 SELECT (
                SELECT * 
                FROM myTable
                FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES 
            ) AS data 
                    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
                        FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

i have not read any in docs that both can be used but just checking if this is possible in a way or not

Comment: You can't use an `OFFSET` without an `ORDER BY`. **Post** the error if you're getting one, it often tells you what the problem is. Your `OFFSET`, where it is makes no sense too, as the above *should* only return 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the for json on the inside and the fetch on the outside, put the fetch on the inside, and put the for json on the outside. For example

```
create table #t(i int, c char);     
insert #t select 1, 'a' union all select 2, 'b';

select  i, c
from    (
            select      i, c
            from        #t
            order by    i
            offset      1 rows
            fetch       next 1 rows only
        ) t
for json auto
```

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to, I am using the column name.

Comment: Ah, roger that. Yeah, I should have used a less ambiguous token as an identifier. Lazy example code!